# Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

when I try to connect with add cloud Firestore SDK to your app it shows me an error.

error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUoWM.png)

image of `bulid.gradle` project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwIxv.png)

image of project.setting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDlwI.png)

Please, help me with this...

```
plugins {

    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.faltu3"
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put below dependency in build.gradle(projectname)
" classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' "

And " apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' " in build.gradle(:app)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in **project level** build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}
```

Add this in **app level** build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```